# multi-thread run processes simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, junit4

I am currently interested in learning about Multi-threading. I have written a piece of code. And my question is if this the correct way. I later want to implement this in another code of mine. My idea was to run multiple threads existing of the same class. So let's say 5 threads and they all have a runner class inside them. What I want to implement in another code, is that I want to run multiple browsers at once. So, I have a class Browser. And then I have 5 threads with the class Browser. And they are all working simultaneously but don't know each other, so they don't have any interaction with each other at all.

So is this idea OK then?

```
class Runner implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + i);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}


public class BasisDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread runner1 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 1");
        runner1.start();

        Thread runner2 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 2");
        runner2.start();
    }

}
```

Is this a good practise and does it support my idea?

Or is using multi-threading even unnecessary. 
I don't know it for sure.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: so you mean you want 5 threads run independently and without any interactions?

Comment: @JunbangHuang yes that's correct. But they do have to start all at once. And they have to do their jobs 24/7 they are all from the same objects let's say Browser as example. So 5 browsers start at once. And they have to do tasks for an hour and then sleep for a day as example. Because the app is running 24/7 in the background. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: so if I have 5 browsers, one have 5 threads inside each, and you want 25 threads start at the same time?

Comment: Oh no the idea is very simple. Just refer to my code example of the runner in the description. Just 5 threads like, example: `Thread browser1 = new Thread(new Browser(), "Browser 1");`. They have to stay active 24/7 and do tasks in a certain hour.

Comment: actually keeping alive threads don't sound good.But it depends on the purpose of the bussiness.When and In which condition your thread comes back to continue process?Sometimes you need to schedule timertask so when the time is ready thread is being created and computing but sometimes you need to keep alive it like in Network listening.So please share your bussiness logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your idea would work. If you try this code below.

```
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You will find that the time is actually the same, which mean these two lines are executed almost at the same time.

In term of your code:

```
Thread runner1 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 1");
runner1.start();

Thread runner2 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 2");
runner2.start();
```

These threads will be executed at almost the same time, that's why your idea will work.

To make it more accurate. You can switch your codes:

```
Thread runner1 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 1");
Thread runner2 = new Thread(new Runner(), "Runner 2");
runner1.start();
runner2.start();
```

If you want to make the timing even more accurate. You can use [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). It allows a set of thread to wait for each other and start at the same time. Here is demo codes:

```
class Demo {
   final CyclicBarrier barrier;

   class Broswer implements Runnable {
     Worker() { }
     public void run() {
       while (!done()) {
         try {
           // wait for other threads
           barrier.await();
           // work for something, in your case an hour, but how can you control that
           // work....
           // sleep for a certain time
           sleep(certain time)
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           return;
         } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
           return;
         }
       }
     }
   }

   public static main(String args[]) {
     barrier = new CyclicBarrier(N);
     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
       new Thread(new Broswer()).start();

     // wait until all done, in your case, forever.
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think this solution is the best comment by now. This I think supports the idea which I have described. If you have a better version or links to share please do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3138008 glad that I can help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on the right track. Each thread will have no reference of each other, since you defined them as separate objects. They would both be able to contain their own data, execute their own methods, completely independently of one another.

One way you could confirm they are executing simultaneously is to make your loop start from a random number, that way you will see the console output incrementing beginning from two different numbers. (i.e. 100, 50, 101, 102, 51, 52, ...)

What you have outlined is the most common way to create threads in Java, you can read more about it [here](http://http:/https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) if you have questions later on.

Comment: Thank you @benssky, so using multi-threading is a preferable as I describe my idea in the description. Because later on in another code I want to run 5 browsers and they have to stay active 24/7 and they have TimedWaiting. They have to execute a task for one hour and then go back to sleep. They don't interact with each other they only share the same class. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think this would be a viable option then from what you're describing. Glad I could help, let me know if you have any other questions about it!

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Thread, not 5

> Or is using multi-threading even unnecessary. I don't know it for sure.

If using the same class to do the same work, then No, no need for 5 threads. You only need one thread to run a task daily in the background.

If you want a copy everyday of a daily newspaper, would you send *one* of you children to the store with a dollar in hand each morning or would you send *five* of your children each with a dollar in hand?

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

Also, Java provide a slick facility for this kind of work where you are scheduling tasks to be done in the background regularly: [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Search Stack Overflow for more info, and read the Oracle Tutorial on Executors.

Comment: The idea is that I want to have 5 browsers fire up and do their work. Not one thread that does 5 different tasks or 1 task executing it 5 times. It has to act as different object. So object browser 1, 2 ... 5 and every browser has the same job to perform. Thanks for your comment.